# Isolated CSS files not working for EditForm Inputs

Tags: css, asp.net, blazor

Let's say I have the following elements on a `MyComponent.razor` file:

```html
<label class="form-label" for="myInput">Text Field</label>
<InputText class="form-control" id="myInput" @bind-Value="@Something"/>
```

If I setup a `MyComponent.razor.css` file, I'm able to target the label element but not the InputText. Regular HTML inputs work as expected.

```css
label {
  color: blue; /* This works */
}

/* Neither of the following works */
input {
  background: red;
}

.form-control {
  background: red;
}

#myInput {
  background: red;
}
```

I styled the label to see if there is a caching issue but looks like it's not that.

Inspecting the elements, the input field doesn't use the same generated hash for the App.styles.css class of the component (**label** and the other elements of the component use `b-rbinozve8m`, when the **input** seems to be using this guid `_bl_9d02f742-2a91-4e7b-aede-108ae5da9f8a`). Perhaps this is where the mismatch occurs and the css can't properly target the input field.

Using inline styles and  tags within the razor file works as expected, only the isolated .razor.css file seems to be troublesome.

##### MyComponent.razor

```html
<!-- This is fine -->
<style>
  .form-control {
     background: red;
  }
</style>

<!-- This is fine too -->
<InputText style="background: red;" class="form-control" id="myInput" @bind-Value="@Something"/>
```

It looks like this is an `InputText` to `input` conversion issue but I'm not sure if that's the expected behavior or a bug. Using style tags in my razor component is fine but I would rather have it as an isolated file to keep consistency within the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputText` is a component therefore it has its own css Isolation. If you want to apply css to child components, you need to use the `::deep`  pseudo-element.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#child-component-support)